# Developing an Android app with monthly subscription

Tags: android

I want to develop an app which I stream basic text information about sports. First of all I believe I need a server which my users connect to see my stream as soon as something new is published. But I don't have an idea about how to build something like that. I did some search on web to find lessons or answers but I wasn't able to find anything useful. If it's true that I need a server, is Java language good to code server's program? Because I only know a little bit of Java.

And I want my app to have a monthly fee. I'm completely new to programming but I guess I need a database to keep track of my user information. Do I have to build my own user membership system - which people register with their e-mails etc- for all this? Is it hard to do that? And again I don't have any source of information about this one too.

I'm lost at this point. I don't know what to search to get some answers. So I'm asking you guys. What do I need to build an app with monthly fee that streams live information? I'm not expecting a full answer here but at least I believe you guys can tell me where to look for answers. Thanks.

Comment: well it's obvious that i'm totally new to programming and i have much to learn. instead of giving a simple answer you guys down vote me. lol thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

While I agree the question is very vague and open (we could write a thesis on the topic in question and everyone will have their own way to complete) my suggestion would be to research the following:

1. Java - read as much as you can about the language and ensure that you are happy with (or know where you can get access to good helpers) the syntax (you mention that you know a little about Java so that is a good start).
2. Android programming in general. Look up the Activity lifecycle (The Android documentation is good, read as much as you can, follow the examples and try out the tutorials!  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)
3. Read up on Firebase; this should make the server side a little simpler (although I have only a parsing knowledge (i.e., none) of Firebase, it looks like it will be a good start). Again walk through the examples / tutorials; do the Hello World and then pull it apart to see if you can figure out how it is holding together.

Then when you have questions (which you will, we all do!) come back and I know that you will get some great help!

Once you have a few applications under your belt (personal 'play' apps) then and only then would I consider looking at the Google Play API (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/).

Hope this gets you on the starting grid at least! Good luck!
Gav